# Disable a select box until a textbox is filled

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I have a textbox and a select box:

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="input-group " >
            <span class="input-group-addon white" >Weight</span>
            <input class="form-control weight" title="Enter the gross weight" type="text" id="weight" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="input-group ">
            <span class="input-group-addon white">Barrel Size</span>
            <select class="form-control gray" id="sizeSelect" title="Select an option">
                <option value="Small">Small</option>
                <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
                <option value="Large">Large</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When a size is selected it subtracts a certain amount from the weight. So I want to make sure users don't select a size before entering a weight.

My question is how to disable the selectbox until a weight(numeric) is entered?
Something like this?

```
        $(".weight").change(function () {
            if (this.value <= 0 || this.value == null) {
                $("#sizeSelect").prop("disabled", true)
            }
            else {
                $("#sizeSelect").prop("disabled", false)
            }
        });
```

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Should work

```js
//makes select disabled on load
$('#sizeSelect').attr('disabled', true);

//this function runs on input 
$('#weight').on('input', function() {
  let val = this.value;
  
  if (val.length > 0) {
    $('#sizeSelect').attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('#sizeSelect').attr('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
  <div class="input-group ">
    <span class="input-group-addon white">Weight</span>
    <input class="form-control weight" title="Enter the gross weight" type="text" id="weight" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
  <div class="input-group ">
    <span class="input-group-addon white">Barrel Size</span>
    <select class="form-control gray" id="sizeSelect" title="Select an option">
      <option value="Small">Small</option>
      <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
      <option value="Large">Large</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. your idea of disabling was right. However those disable property change will act only when the change is made in text input. to make the select input disabled by default you have to add the disabled prop on document.ready() or to say, out of the .change()  of text input.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("#sizeSelect").prop("disabled", true);

$(".weight").change(function () {
            if (this.value <= 0 || this.value == null) {
                $("#sizeSelect").prop("disabled", true);
            }
            else {
                $("#sizeSelect").prop("disabled", false);
            }
        });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="input-group " >
            <span class="input-group-addon white" >Weight</span>
            <input class="form-control weight" title="Enter the gross weight" type="text" id="weight" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="input-group ">
            <span class="input-group-addon white">Barrel Size</span>
            <select class="form-control gray" id="sizeSelect" title="Select an option">
                <option value="Small">Small</option>
                <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
                <option value="Large">Large</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: There is no need to disable the select element on document load by using JS. You can use the `disabled` HTML property instead

Answer (score 1):

You could use `keyup`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#sizeSelect").prop("disabled", true)
    $(".weight").on("keyup", function() {
    var length = $.trim($(this).val()).length === 0;
    $("#sizeSelect").prop('disabled', length);
  });
});
```